# How to detect sign toggle in javascript array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have example of javascript array as below.

```
var exampleArr1 = [5,4,1,-2,-5,-7,5,1,2,-3,2,4...];
var exampleArr2 = [-5,-4,1,2,5,7,-5,1,2,3,-2,4...];
```

I would to create function to detect sign change and return with position, e.g.  `['index','num1','num2']` For example.

```
function getSignChange(exampleArr1){
 ...
 return someArray;
}
```

return shoud be

```
[
  [2,1,-2],  //index = 2 change from 1 to -2
  [5,-7,5],  //index = 5 change from -7 to 5
  [8,2,-3],  //index = 8 change from 2 to -3
]
```

Any advice or guidance on this would be greatly appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: How about some code between the brackets `{...}`? It'd be nice to know how thesse values changed in the first place. Read on [ask]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this will help you:

```js
var exampleArr1 = [5,4,1,-2,-5,-7,5,1,2,-3,2,4];
var exampleArr2 = [-5,-4,1,2,5,7,-5,1,2,3,-2,4];

function getSignChange(arr){
 let positive = arr[0] >= 0; 
 return arr.map((item, index) => {
  if (positive && item < 0 || !positive && item >= 0) {
    positive = arr[index] >= 0
    return [index-1, arr[index-1], item]
  }
  
 }).filter(x => x != null);
}

console.log(getSignChange(exampleArr1));
console.log(getSignChange(exampleArr2));
```

Comment: Dear peaxkl, thank you very much.